# Problems in office 365 integration with graph API using Java SDK

Tags: java, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have been following https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java project for getting all the mails using `Microsoft Graph API`. This project works fine based on my changed configuration.

However, this follows `OAuth` authentication and I have to configure redirect url, and while running project, I got authentication code as query param on given url.

I stuck at two points :

1. How to by pass `redirect_url` concept, since my application is going to run in background. so, is there any way, I can auto capture this `authentication code`?
2. By trading authentication code, I receive `access_token` having `3600 expiry` using below method.

   ```
   OAuth2AccessToken mAccessToken = mOAuthService.getAccessToken(authCodeFromURL);
   ```

In above object, receiving below JSON, which does not have refresh token.

```
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "scope": "Files.ReadWrite openid User.Read Mail.Send Mail.ReadWrite",
    "expires_in": 3600,
    "ext_expires_in": 3600,
    "access_token": "encryptedCode",
    "id_token": "encryptedCode"
}
```

I have tried to get the new access token with below method from SDK by using id_token, but it is not working, gives me invalid.

```
OAuth2AccessToken mAccessToken = mOAuthService.refreshAccessToken(idToken);
```

Invalid JSON :

```
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "AADSTS9002313: Invalid request. Request is malformed or invalid.\r\nTrace ID: 03690b71-4056\r\nCorrelation ID: b70a7b7b-963b-4cd6\r\nTimestamp: 2019-05-22 08:24:33Z",
    "error_codes": [9002313],
    "timestamp": "2019-05-22 08:24:33Z",
    "trace_id": "03690b71-4056-49b9",
    "correlation_id": "b70a7b7b-963b-4cd6"
}
```

What is `id_token`?

How can I refresh this `access_token`? Or Is there any other way/method to do it?

Kindly note, I am looking for solution with Java SDK.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send Office 365 email from Wcf Windows Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54576460/send-office-365-email-from-wcf-windows-service)

Comment: @MarcLaFleur I am looking solution with Java SDK.

Comment: Your issue isn't language or SDK specific, it is architectural. You're using the OAught Authorization Code grant where you should be using the Client Credentials grant.  Microsoft Graph (and the SDKs) don't handle the OAuth side of things, they simply consume the token you already retrieved.